# Retrieve the first record using only a WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I need to retrieve the first record created by a customer, using only a WHERE clause.  I cannot use LIMIT, ORDER BY, etc.

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE customer_id = 1
  AND created = ? the earliest timestamp for that customer
```

Edit: In anticipation of those who will ask, it's a limitation of a specific case in the current framework I'm using. Don't worry about it.  I just have to do it this way.  If it can't be done, just let me know it can't be done.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit2:** Thanks everyone but I can't use any joins either.  Any more ideas or can it simply not be done?

Comment: Is this homework?  If so then you should tag it as homework.

Comment: I left school 10 years ago... this isn't homework lol

Comment: can u indicate which framework does not allow LIMIT during query?

Comment: All frameworks allow LIMIT, it's just in this particular rare case it can't be used.  It's not worth explaining, it will take too long and isn't relevant.

Comment: Congratulations on leaving school 10 years ago, BadHorsie, but I think everyone is a bit curious what real-life situation you're in that you can't use ORDER BY or LIMIT clauses.  That's why it sounds like homework.

Comment: Haha, these kind of replies always derail my question.  I tried to insert a disclaimer because I knew they were coming but apparently that didn't stop anything!  As I already said, it's too long and irrelevant an explanation that will not serve to help anyone except me and especially not anyone who may visit this thread in the future.  It's a fairly straight forward question I just needed an answer for.

Comment: can u add new column to the table? or create new table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE customer_id = 1 AND created IN (
    SELECT min(created) AS MinCreated
    FROM mytable
    WHERE customer_id = 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`...AND created = MIN(SELECT timestamp FROM mytable)` does this work?

Comment: Not without adding an `INNER JOIN` to the `SELECT` on `customer_id`, or you'll get the earliest `timestamp` for any `customer_id`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use,

```
select * from mytable where customer_id = 1
  AND (select count(*) from mytable) <=1
```

Comment: there is no automatic rownum column available and I believe this is hinting to `SQL Server` where it's possible to add one while the question states `MySQL` that doesn't have that abbility.

Comment: I can't use ORDER BY anyway, as I said in my question.